# Apk built from android studio crashing but one directly ran on my device is fine

Tags: android

The Apk of my project built by Android Studio is crashing. However when I install the app by running the app on my phone using AS it works fine. What is the problem ?

Comment: Its impossible to know what exactly the crash is without any log, or crashreport. Check if you can grab the stacktrace.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Build APK` from `Menu` like below screenshot, to send APK file wherever.

[image]

Comment: is this helpful ?

Comment: Thats what I did

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing issue while generating apk using Android Studio 2.3.+ onwards. Try creating APK by checking both V1(Jar Signature) and V2 (Full APK Signature).Give it a try if that sorts out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Rebuild Project" first and then "Build APK".